# Where do I start when I'm trying to create a small video game in Bluej?

Tags: bluej

I have a project where I'm trying to create a video game and I have no clue where to start. Can someone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://handmadehero.org/faq